# rails notices not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm in Rails 4 using Bootstrap

This is my create action in my controller:

```
  def create
    @contest = Contest.new(contest_params) 
    if @contest.save
      flash[:notice] = "Contest saved successfully"
        redirect_to @contest
    else
        redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Project not saved'
    end
  end
```

How come there is no notice when I submit the form? Is there something I am missing? I'm a beginner and have not been able to figure this out.

I have the following in my layout already:

```
  <body>
    <p class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
      <p class="alert"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>

    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

      <%= yield %>

    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

  </body>
```

Comment: have your written `<%= flash[:notice] %>` tag on your view? This tag displays notice on the front end

Comment: Edited my question with the relevant information

Comment: Flash notices basically last for only one request, So do make sure that when you are setting a flash message, you server is not making another request which might be erasing the flash message and try inspecting flash hash to check if it has any values!

Comment: @JetAbe has written up all.

Comment: @Himesh not sure I understand all you are saying a bit advanced for me

Comment: @nithin his answer did not work for me unfortunately

Comment: Edited my question with more recent code

Comment: Can you try few basic things..1. replace the <%= flash[:notice] %> with hardcoded string see if the layout is getting rendered . 2. Remove the     <%= render 'layouts/header' %> in case there is some conflict.. else from your updated code i still don;t see         redirect_to url, :flash => { :notice => "notice" }

Comment: I removed the rendering header and saw that it was covering the notice.

Comment: Can you accept my answer with an upvote I have updated it as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
 flash[:notice] = 'Project saved successfully'
 redirect_to about_path
```

redirect with flash was broken in some versions.
**Workaround if you want to try:**

```
redirect_to url, :flash => { :notice => "notice" }
```

**also edit your layout**

Remove the layouts header in case it conflicts.

```
 <body>
     <p class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
      <p class="alert"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>

      <%= yield %>

    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

  </body>
```

Comment: the formatting of your answer is a bit confusing, since some code is not code format. I'll try and do what I think you mean.

Comment: oops.. sorry..changed it

Comment: My problem was that my rendering header nav bar was covering my flash message

Answer (score 1):

[Read about the flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash). You must display the flash content in your html views, preferably in your layout.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
    <% end -%>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edited my questions with relevant information any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Set `<%= flash[:notice] %>` in `root_path` in your html view.

Comment: edited my question with relevant information any idea?