# Custom Field Validations message in view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method in controller to check if email already exists in database table.
I need to display the validation messages below email text box similar to the image and not using flash[:error] = "メール変更に失敗しました！".

The validation is done in controller, where we check if the email-Id

[image]

Controller method:

```
def update_email
  @user_login = UserLogin.find(params[:id])

  if @email_check = UserLogin.where(:email => params[:update_email]).first   
    redirect_to "/works?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&commit=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2", notice: params[:id] + 'idの メールは既に存在します！' 
  else
        @update_email = UserLogin.where(:user_id =>  @user_login ).update_all(:email => params[:update_email])

  if @update_email
    UserLogin.where(:user_id => params[:id]).update_all(:updated_at => Time.zone.now)
    flash[:success] = "メール変更！"
    redirect_to works_path
  else
    flash[:error] = "メール変更に失敗しました！"
    redirect_to works_path
  end
  end 
  end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :works,:id => "email_validate", :url => {:action => 'update_email',:id => userdetails.user_id} do  %>
<td><%= email_field_tag :update_email,nil,:id =>"email",:class => "form-control" ,:placeholder =>'新しいメールアドレス。。。。', required: true %><br/></td>
<td><%= button_to("変更", {}, {:onclick => "return confirm('メールをリセットします｡よろしいでしょうか？')", :class => "btn btn-primary", :method => :update_email, :remote => true}) %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what's the problem? is your code doesnt work? is there any error?

Comment: @mrvncaragay The above code works. But it gives a "FLASH" message. I need to display the message "メール変更に失敗しました！" in a balloon below the text box as in the image, if the email address does not exist in database.

Comment: so it does redirect, but the notice is not showing?

Comment: read on this, i might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031396/rails-notices-not-appearing

Answer (score 1):

```
In controller:

    flash[:notice] = 'メールは既に存在します！!'

    redirect_to works_path

In view:

    <%= form_for :maintanance_works, :url => {:action => 'update_email',:id => userdetails.user_id} do  %>
      <td>
        <%= email_field_tag :update_email, nil,:class => "form-control" ,:placeholder =>'新しいメールアドレス。。。。', required: true %><br/>
        <p class="notice" style="color:red;font-size:12pt;">
        <%= flash[:notice] %></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= button_to("変更", {}, {:onclick => "return confirm('メールをリセットします｡よろしいでしょうか？')", :class => "btn btn-primary", :method => :update_email, :remote => true}) %></td>
    <% end %>

**Display flash message below your textbox**
```